# Distinguish between web api routes and mvc routes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I started developing an application supported by **Web API 2**, because I just wanted to retrieve data in a RESTful way.

Then I needed to add some HTML to the site in order to allow administrators manage the information provided, so I created some **MVC 5** controller to return HTML. Now I want to distinguish between Web API routes and MVC routes, without affecting, if possible, Web API routes, which are in production.

**Web API routes: My mistake here was removing the "api" prefix when I firstly developed this, which would have solved the collision now**

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults:
            new {
                 controller = "Parking",
                 action = "Get",
                 id = RouteParameter.Optional
                 }
        );
}
```

**MVC Routes: default routing. MVC Controller name is Administration, that is, MVC routes are intended for administration site only**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Parking", action = "Get", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

The problem is that MVC routes don't have the opportunity to match because WebAPI routes match first. It doesn't really matter how MVC routes need to be changed as long as they just **work**, since they are not in production yet; it's better for me to **keep Web API routes** as they are now.

I've tried:

- Switching the order of registration of web api routes and mvc routes in Global.asax.cs
- Using "web" as prefix for the MVC controllers, but the routing mechanism thinks "web" is a controller and it is not found (Web api routing wins again).
- I couldn't come up with a proper constraint to avoid this collision.
- Hardcode "Administration" replacing "{controller}" in the MVC route pattern.

Is there some trick here to resolve the collision?

Comment: Then do the reverse of what would normally be done for web api. web api would normally register `api` prefix and map before mvc to avoid collision. register a prefix for mvc and map it before web api routes. You could even try using attribute routing for mvc and set prefix there

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work (see list of tries in the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally made it with the following constraint in WebApiConfig:

```
constraints: new { controller = @"(?!web).*" }
```

So, this is my WebApiConfig:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults:
                    new
                    {
                        controller = "Parking",
                        action = "Get",
                        id = RouteParameter.Optional
                    },
                constraints: new { controller = @"(?!web).*" }
            );
        }
    }
```

And my RouteConfig:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "web/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Parking", action = "Get", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The web prefix for MVC controllers will work. In this case, configure the routing for MVC first (before configuring the routing for API).

Add the following constraint to the API

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults:
        new {
             controller = "Parking",
             action = "Get",
             id = RouteParameter.Optional
             },
    constraints: new { controller = @"^web" },
  );
```

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work, despite switching the routing registration order between WebAPI and MVC. I used "web" as prefix for MVC but when solving the route it entered the WebAPI routing rule and expected "web" to be a controller.

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know also (since you are just starting developing this Web API), the MVC controller and Web API controllers are now merged/unified in MVC 6.0 (ASP.NET Core 1.0). So there is no more confusion as to what controller you are inheriting from. Other than that there is also big performance benefits if using the .NET Core framework.

Comment: Cool, I'll take that into account, maybe it deserves some research on that issue!